# Python os.chdir() to root directory actually changes directory to current directory

Tags: python

I am working on a project on path `D:/code/project`.

**project.py**

```py
import os
import argparse

def create(path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        os.chdir(path)
        app = open("app.py", "w+")
        app.write("print(\"Hello world!\")")
    else:
        path_list = path.split("/")
        for i in path_list:
            try:
                os.mkdir(i)
            except FileExistsError:
                pass
            except FileNotFoundError:
                print("Invalid path")
                exit()
            os.chdir(i)
        app = open("app.py", "w+")
        app.write("print(\"Hello world!\")")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    create_parser = parser.add_subparsers().add_parser("create")
    create_parser.add_argument("path", nargs="?", default=".", metavar="path", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    create(vars(args)["path"])
```

Basically, it has a custom command called `create` which takes `path` as an argument. When it detects that `path` already exists, it will create a `app.py` at the directory specified, and if it does not, it will try and create the path and `app.py`.

However, when I run

```
D:/code/project> python project.py create D:/newpath
```

Instead of creating a new directory `newpath` under `D:`, it creates `newpath` under my current directory (`D:/code/project`).

How do I change it such that changing directory to a root directory will actually switch correctly?

Comment: `app = open(path+"app.py", "w+")` or use path.join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with this line:

```
path_list = path.split("/")
```

On windows, that doesn't correctly split the path. It leaves the drive letter `'D:'` as a fragment all by itself, but when you try to change directory to that path, it does nothing (assuming the current directory was on `D:` somewhere). It is the same behavior you get with the `cd` command on a command prompt. Drive letters in paths are pretty weird, they don't work like normal path prefixes.

To correctly split the path, use `os.path.split(path)`. It will correctly use `'D:/'` as the first element of the path, which when you change to it will put you on the root folder of your drive.

If you're using a recent version of Python (3.4+), you could also try using [the `pathlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for a better, more object oriented way of manipulating paths:

```
from pathlib import Path

def create(path_str):
    path = Path(path_str)
    path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)  # creates parent folders as needed
    with open(path / 'app.py', 'w') as app:  # / operator joins path fragments
        app.write('print("Hello world!")')
```